# Using Backbone model in jQuery function/plugin

Tags: backbone.js

On my page, I will have a slider which will have html inside, that will be populated using data fetched from the server.

I would like for the slider to be built and populated using jQuery, leaving Backbone to handle the viewing and events.

For this, I would need the data from the Backbone model, which leads to my question:

**Is it fine to pass the model into jQuery OR would it be better to leave everything to the jQuery function and do a `$.ajax` fetch in the function instead.**

**Backbone**

```
define(['backbone', 'models/model','slider'], function(Backbone, Model, Slider) {

    var View = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function() {
            $('#slider').Slider( this.model );
            var template = _.template();
            this.$el.html(template);
            return this;
        }
     });
     return View;
});
```

**jQuery**

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

   "use strict";

    $.fn.Slider = function(model) {

        // do stuff with model

    }

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement the event handling and logic directly in the backbone view, where you already have the model and all other backbone objects you might possibly want to use. If you need the model data in the slider initialization you should not pass the model itself, but the json representation of the model data using

```
$('#slider').Slider( this.model.toJSON() );
```